# Ansible when condition fails each time

Tags: ansible

I have written an ansibe playbook to check if oswatcher is installed. if not, install it.

shell script to check the software is installed

```
#!/bin/bash

#Validation check that checks if oswatcher is installed
oswatcher=$(rpm -qa | grep "^oswatcher*" || echo "not_installed")
echo "$oswatcher"
```

this play here checks the shell scripts output and validates if it has to run the install play or not

```
- name: Execute script to check if oswatcher is installed
  script: "{{ oswatch_home }}/version_details.sh"
  register: oswatcher

- name: Print the Output
  debug:
    msg: "You can think the Application is installed, it is {{ oswatcher.stdout }}"

- include: oswatch-install.yml
  when: oswatcher.stdout == "not_installed"
```

Please see the output

```
PLAY [integration] *******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxxxx]
ok: [xxxxxx]

TASK [app/oswatch : Execute script to check if oswatcher is installed] ***************************************************************
changed: [xxxxx1]
changed: [xxxxx2]

TASK [app/oswatch : Print the Output] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [xxxxxx1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "You can think the Application is installed, it is oswatcher-7.3.3-2.el6.noarch\r\n"
}
ok: [xxxxxx2] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "You can think the Application is installed, it is not_installed\r\n"
}

TASK [app/oswatch : create project directory "/tmp/oswatch"] *************************************************************************
skipping: [xxxxxx1]
skipping: [xxxxxx2]
```

My logic matches not_installed and validates whether to run the install play or not, It even prints it perfect not able to understand the hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

Change the task to below and see if it is serving the purpose.If it is still not working, please run your playbook with -vvv and post complete output.

```
    - include: oswatch-install.yml
      when: "not_installed" in oswatcher.stdout
```

Comment: you are correct, it work as such, but the yaml syntaxing goes like this  
                                                                                                                               when: "'not_installed' in oswatcher.stdout"      thanks a ton! still unsure why the condition i use dont work

Comment: Thank you. I changed quotes in my answer accordingly.
Your initial condition was verifying whether 'not_installed' is the value of your variable 'oswatcher'. My condition checks whether 'not_installed' is part of this variable.
Print 'oswatcher' to understand it fluently.

Comment: @BinnyThomas Pay attention to `\r\n`. It's in the variable value, it's not in the string you compared it to.

Comment: you are right @techraf, no wonder my logic kept failing. great job!!